# Approximating an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

I wish to solve the IVP:

\begin{align}
x(0) =& -1 \\
x'   =& 1 + x^2 - t^3
\end{align}

With a fourth order taylor series method, I solved the ODE on the interval [0, 2] and then made the following plot:

[image: plot of the above IVP on the interval [0, 2]]

- Is this correct? I have tried to verify with SAGE Math's ODE solver, but it couldn't compute the result. Likewise, I failed with wolfram.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Wolfram seems to work fine: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%280%29%3D-1%2Cx%27%28t%29%3D1%2Bx%28t%29%5E2-t%5E3 (Just put in the original ODE and look at how close it looks)

Comment: It gives me a vague plot of x vs t, and x` vs x, what else can I do? What do you mean by "look at how close it looks?"

Comment: Here is an approximate solution $ x \left( t \right) =-1+2\,t-2\,{t}^{2}+{\frac {8}{3}}{t}^{3}-{\frac{43}{12}}{t}^{4}+O( {t}^{5} ).$

Comment: I used numerical integration and the plot is very similar to your. Using Taylor, I obtained the same development as  Mhenni Benghorbal posted but this leads to a totally different plot. May I ask how you did process ? Thanks for answering.

Comment: I did a 4th order taylor series method